# Cross domain ajax errors because of different ports in Vagrant setup

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, virtualhost, vagrant

I am developing a web application with this setup:

```
Production:
  frontend.myapp.com
  appserver.myapp.com
  auth.myapp.com

Development:
  localhost:8080 (frontend)
  localhost.com:3010 (appserver)
  localhost.com:3011 (auth)
```

Frontend is an angularjs SPA served with nginx. Appserver is a rails app that exposes apis (users, items, orders...). Auth is another rails app that handle authentication with omniauth.

In production, we use different subdomains as virtualhosts. In development, we use different ports (because it is easier to configure in vagrant).

Everything works fine, except for one thing: the angular app (the frontend) sometimes needs to make an ajax request to the auth server, and this is considered as a cross domain attack because the frontend port is 8080 and the auth port is 3011. The problem does not exist in production because we use subdomains.

How can I prevent the cross domain error ?

---

One fix would be to use subdomains in development as well. (eg, in my hostfile:

```
10.2.0.15 frontend-local.myapp.com
10.2.0.15 appserver-local.myapp.com
10.2.0.15 auth-local.myapp.com
```

(10.2.0.15 being my vagrant machine ip)

I like this fix because my local setup would be more like the production setup (using subdomains instead of ports).

But then after a vagrant reload the ip of my guest (lucid32) machine would change, and I need to edit my hostfile again...

And I havn't found a way to tell vagrant to assign a static IP...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Accessing a different port violates [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), that's why it's not working. You could use JSONp requests, but you won't need them in production. How about if you set [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#The_HTTP_response_headers) to allow every domain on your local machine? Then it should work at least in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with setting up your hosts file.

Making Vagrant assign the machine a static ip is pretty easy, try this:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.2.0.15"
```

Comment: I've tried that, but with this setup, I can ping 10.2.0.15 from the vagrant machine. But I can't ping 10.2.0.15 from the host machine (macOS). If I do `ifconfig` in the guest, I see 10.2.0.15 just besides the IP alocated automatically. I have no idea why I cannot ping it from the host.